# Change variables based on time elapsed

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create  a program within which the user interacts with a virtual pet. This pet has attributes such as hunger, which is just stored as an integer between 1-10. Is there a way to decrease the value of said variable based on how much time has passed (since the pet was last fed, let's say)?

Hopefully i can use it to create a function like this:

```
    static void hungerDecrease(CPet pet)
    {
        bool needsFeeding = false;
        // some method of checking if say 4 hours has passed and if so set needsFeeding to be true
        if (needsFeeding == true)
        {
            pet.Hunger -= 1;
        }
    }
```

The class CPet looks like this:

```
    public class CPet 
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Gender;
        // Attributes belonging to pets, with values being defined upon creation.
        public int Hunger = 5;
        public int Boredom = 5;
        public int Happiness = 5;
        public int Intelligence = 1;
        public CPet(string name, string gender)
        {
            Name = name;
            Gender = gender;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want them to decrease over time like in Sims or do you want to update them when you check the value?

Comment: Take a look at timers ...

Comment: I don't really understand the difference between those two, won't they just do the same thing? I suppose I'd just like for a way for the values to depreciate over time, so the first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class CPet 
{
    public string Name;
    public DateTime LastFed;
    ...
}

static void hungerDecrease(CPet pet)
{
    if (DateTime.Now > pet.LastFed.AddHours(4))
    {
        pet.Hunger -= 1;
        pet.LastFed = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work while the program isn't running, does it? Thus the values reset every time you restart?

Comment: Oh, you need the code that works "while the program isn't running"? Please, add it to your question. How about - when the computer is shut down, should it still work? On a serious note, you create these objects somewhere in code. If they survive program restart, you must be storing them. Store `LastFed` value and restore it when you recreate `CPet`.

Comment: No I don't need them to, I just wanted to ask if it that was how it worked.